# No sending duplicates

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to make my first bot on telegram. His task is simple: it scrapes from ebay the last items posted and sends me an update on telegram.
I thought to use a telegram job to do that:

```
context.job_queue.run_repeating(items_call, context=chat_id, name=str(chat_id), interval=6)
```

where items_call is the function that calls the ebay scraper every 6 seconds

The problem i'm facing with is this: i want my bot to remember the items that he already sent on the chat, i don't know how to do it, is there a specific function?

i'm using python-telegram-bot library

Thanks in case of help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbVaE.png)

I'd like some advice or helps... thx

Comment: Please copy and paste your code directly into your question, rather than using an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you want a set.

At some point in your code, you want to declare the set:

```
sent_jobs = set()
```

Then, in your items call function, you'll want to use the set:

```
def items_call:
    # ... Code you already had here
    for its in items:
        if its in sent_jobs:   # Check if the item has been sent before
            continue
        else:
            # ... Do code you had previously
            sent_jobs.add(its) # Add the item to the set
```

Comment: i cannot do it in this way once it is online... i already tried